# Reference points of the glyphs and scaling them

Tags: font-design, fontlab-studio, font-forge

Suppose that I am designing a new font in either fontforge or fontlab and suppose that I already have a model font. What do I need to do so that the reference points of the glyphs in my new fonts is the same as the reference points of the glyphs in my model font and the corresponding glyphs would have the same scale? I just would like my new font to be consistent with my model font.

Comment: So, you just want to change an existing font-file?

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly that you want to create a metrically equivalent font?